# Python class and namespace?

Tags: python, class, namespaces

lets say I wanna define a class name MyClass.

and I wanna use that class. so,

```
class MyClass():

    blabla

MyClass = MyClass(abc)
```

say I wanna make a function and use MyClass in that function. What I found out is that the following code will through an exception :

```
def MyFunction():
    MyClass = MyClass(abc)

MyFunction(123)
```

any help? I can do like

```
    Myclass1 = MyClass(abc)
```

but I think I'm missing something basic about namespaces. thank you!

Comment: What exception are you getting??

Answer (score 2):

When you execute

```
MyClass = MyClass(abc)
```

you are creating a new instance of `MyClass`, and assigning it to the class itself, whereas with `Myclass1 = MyClass(abc)`, you don't overwrite the class. Overwriting the class shouldn't throw an exception (the exception may be to do with calling your `MyFunction()` method with an argument, since it doesn't take any, or perhaps calling the constructor of `MyClass` with an argument, since that doesn't take any either), but I imagine it isn't what you intend to do.

`Myclass1 = MyClass(abc)` looks alright to me (besides the argument being passed), although I would recommend using `myClass1` (or even better, the generally used python style of `my_class1`) for variables, rather than capitalizing the fist letter, as it prevents confusion about which object is a class.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass = MyClass(abc)
```

The above line is the same as doing this:

```
def x():
   print 'Hello'
   return 'Hello'

x() # outputs Hello
x = x() # Also ouputs 'Hello' (since x() is called)
x() # Error, since x is now 'Hello' (a string), and you are trying to call it.
```

In python the *name* of a variable is just a pointer to a place in memory. You can freely assign it to another location (object) by pointing it to something else. In fact, most things you define work that way (like methods and classes). They are just names.

Its even stranger if your method doesn't have a return value (like most class `__init__` methods). In that case, the left hand side is `None`, and you'll get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Like this:

```
>>> def x():
...   print 'Hello'
...
>>> x()
Hello
>>> x = x()
Hello
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>>> type(x)
<type 'NoneType'>
```